# NextJS: Question about next/link pre-fetching

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Learning about the `next/link` component in NextJS, I was under the impression that any `<Link />` will pre-fetch the page the href points to.

*`prefetch` - Prefetch the page in the background. Defaults to true. Any  that is in the viewport (initially or through scroll) will be preloaded. Pages using Static Generation will preload JSON files with the data for faster page transitions.* [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link)

However, that doesn't seem to be the case as far as i can tell. working through a tutorial I came across the author used `<NavLink as={...} href="/..." />`. The `as` turned the page into a SPA and I could see in the console I wasn't getting full page refreshes. This surprised me, since just `<Link href="/..." />` *does* seem to trigger a full page refresh. So, I'm confused as to why simply adding the `as` made my pages load immediately on click (SPA) and not trigger a full refresh? I was under the impression by the NextJS documentation that `<Link />` by default does this simply with href.

Comment: When I used "as" and reloaded the page, it shows 404. Do you know how to solve it ?